# Improve left uppercut technique

Tags: boxing

**Goal:**

I am looking for a way to better my left uppercut technique. This can be extremely difficult at times doing this alone. I understand that the power of the uppercut comes from the feet and spring-like motion of the knees and inertia from hip rotation.

**Problem:**

My gym doesn't have uppercut bags and I only see my coach once a week. So mits aren't usually an option. I find that when I am hitting the heavy bag the angle is extremely awkward. The angle that I am using to hit the bag feels like a body uppercut from a long distance.

**Question:**

How can I better the technique of my left uppercut given my circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a hard task, but I have three possibilities for you.

1. Use a mirror and do shadowboxing. In this way you can train form and technique with the capability to have a virtual opponent (yourself ;-) )
2. Create your own Uppercut device from an old tire ex: cut it in half and bring it on a board attached to a wall. Sample: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mzgUx3US5g4
3. For power, you can use isometric contractions combining with bands (see your question about inproving power of left hook)

Comment: Do you by chance have a video or an article on the correct form/technique that I could use to mimic the uppercut movement?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of them but here is a sample ... http://www.sneakpunch.com/sneakpunchtv

Comment: Thank you sir I'll try these in a few hours. I don't think I'll find a tire anywhere soon haha. But will update the post.

Comment: Welcome, if this description is not enough, let me know ... I'll try to find something different if needed :-) btw. I ve built a tire hook bag myself and it is of great value.

Comment: I'd have to buy another pair of gloves.... I feel like the treads from the tire will rip them up... no?

Comment: Yep, also wrap your hands properly. You could probably wrap something around the hard parts of the tire too at first.